# Second column aligns too high in multicol

Tags: multicol

I am using multicol along with currvita, and I am having an issue where the second column of a two-column block is lining up with a heading that comes before the multicol environment. I would really like to have both columns be under the heading, with "Third Item" aligned with "First Item". Any suggestions?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{cv}

\begin{cvlist}{A List Of Items}
   \begin{multicols}{2}
   \item First item
   \item Second item
   \item Third item
   \item Fourth Item
\end{multicols}

\end{cvlist}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Example of the formatting error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that this is about being in vertical mode when you're entering the `multicols` environment.  As a result, the top of the columns is being calculated before the newline is created for your `cvlist` header.  Try something like the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{cv}

\begin{cvlist}{A List Of Items}
   \item ~\vspace{-2\baselineskip}%%
   \begin{multicols}{2}
   \item First item
   \item Second item
   \item Third item
   \item Fourth Item
\end{multicols}

\end{cvlist}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

[image]